# Functions, Structs and Value Semantics in Swift

Tags: swift, struct

If a struct has a function which contains an object, does the struct retain value semantics? Example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var x = 3

    func setX() {
        let y = NSNumber(value: 2)
        x = y.intValue
    }
}
```

The struct doesn't have any members with reference  so it should have value semantics. Does the fact that the function `setX()` has a reference member `y` cause MyStruct to use reference semantics?

Comment: I don't see a question here. "Maintain value semantics" is too vague

Comment: What is MyIntClassWrapper? The function syntax is wrong. – A *self-contained, compilable* example with expected and actual output would be helpful.

Comment: This is pretty easy to investigate in the REPL or a playground. I'd suggest looking into this yourself and then coming back with a more precisely-targeted question.

Answer (score 0):

Structs with `mutating` functions retain the same value semantics as any other structs.

Calling `setX` would mutate the instance it was called on, but NOT any other instances, as they would be distinct copied instances, and not a shared instance (as with reference types).

You can see for yourself in [this example](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57acd87c603420ce5f482bb8):

```
struct Counter {
    var count: Int

    mutating func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
}

var x = Counter(count: 0)
let y = x // a copy is made

print("x: \(x)") // x: Counter(count: 0)
print("y: \(y)") // y: Counter(count: 0)

x.increment()

print("x: \(x)") // x: Counter(count: 1), method target affected
print("y: \(y)") // y: Counter(count: 0), copy unaffected
```